# Eclipse plugin to open zip files

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to open my resource files which are in zip format, 
 Is there any good eclipse plugin out there which allows to open and edit zip files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really like [Zip Editor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zipeditor/) plugin.

Comment: thank you i will accept answer, would you like to suggest other alternatives to zip editor.